# How do I get the current directory using C# that my Windows App Store app is running in?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I have an older desktop app that I am trying to get working so that I can get it in the Windows App Store. When I publish the app, run the installed app from the Start menu, and I call this in C#:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

It's returning:

**C:\Windows\system32**

When the app is actually located here:

**C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CompanyLLC.MyApp_2.0.16.0_neutral__7ec99svkv2pe4\MyApp**

When I run the app from the actual location folder manually (by browsing to it and double-clicking the exe), `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` pulls back the correct location. But when I run the app from the installed location in the Start menu, that's when it doesn't work.

**How do I fix this?**

Note: I am installing the app for testing via publishing it as a side-loading app before uploading to Microsoft. It already got denied by them once for running into the same issue.

Comment: Try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! Please make it an answer so I can mark it and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` works and is cross-platform - included in [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=netstandard-2.1).